# Равномерно закрашивать контур convexHull

Tags: c++, c, opencv

После нахождения выпуклой оболочки произвольной формы, надо закрашивать весь найденный контур с шагом dx по оси ОХ. Знаю х, у, ширину и высоту контура, но не знаю как организовать процесс закрашивания слева направо. Закрашивать попиксельно, шириной dx. В итоге получится несколько картинок, которые будут показывать закрашивание контура.

[image: Нашли выпуклую оболочку, потом ее надо закрашивать с шагом dx.]

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что на входе имеется следующее изображение:

[image: Изображение руки]

Так как свой вариант я взял с гуглокартинок (изображение на самом деле в оттенках серого), то необходимо произвести его бинаризацию:

```
cv::Mat gry_mat = cv::imread("hand.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::threshold(gry_mat, gry_mat, 20, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

Теперь найдём контуры, а затем по ним определим выпуклую оболочку `convex hull`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(gry_mat.clone(), contours
    , cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > hull(contours.size());
for(int i = 0, n = contours.size(); i < n; ++i)
    cv::convexHull(cv::Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false);
```

Если произвести рисование контуров и выпуклой оболочки:

```
cv::Mat dst_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(gry_mat.size(), CV_8UC3);
for(int i = 0, n = contours.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    cv::drawContours(dst_mat, contours, i, cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
    cv::drawContours(dst_mat, hull, i, cv::Scalar(0,255,255));
}
```

... , то изображение будет выглядеть так:

[image: Изображение контуров руки и их выпуклой оболочки]

В вопросе не вполне понятно, нужно ли закрашивать только контур выпуклой оболочки или его же, но за вычетом контура руки. Если только первое, то необходимо создать одну маску оболочки:

```
cv::Mat msk_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(gry_mat.size(), CV_8UC1);
for(int i = 0, n = contours.size(); i < n; ++i)
    cv::drawContours(msk_mat, hull, i, cv::Scalar::all(255), -1);
```

[image: Изображение маски выпуклой оболочки]

... если же второе, то две маски, плюс, выделить их разницу:

```
cv::Mat msk1_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(gry_mat.size(), CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat msk2_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(gry_mat.size(), CV_8UC1);
for(int i = 0, n = contours.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    cv::drawContours(msk1_mat, hull, i, cv::Scalar::all(255), -1);
    cv::drawContours(msk2_mat, contours, i, cv::Scalar::all(255), -1);
}

cv::Mat msk_mat = msk1_mat - msk2_mat;
```

[image: Изображение маски выпуклой оболочки, минус маска руки]

Теперь в `msk_mat` содержится результат, который мы должны получить, но через постепенное закрашивание пикселей длинной `dx`.

Следующий код будет выполнять последовательное закрашивание пикселей по оси OX, выводя при этом результат своей работы в отдельную матрицу, которую можно нарисовать в окне и/или сохранить в файл:

```
const int dx = 10; int ox = 0;

cv::Mat drw_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(msk_mat.size(), CV_8UC1);
for(int row = 0; row < drw_mat.rows; ++row) {
    for(int col = 0; col < drw_mat.cols; ++col) {
        if(msk_mat.at<uchar>(row,col) > 0) {
            drw_mat.at<uchar>(row,col) = 255;

            if(++ox == (dx-1)) {
                ox = 0;
                cv::imshow("win", drw_mat);
                cv::waitKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат в процессе:

[image: Результат в процессе]